# SQL query error according to SQL Fiddle

Tags: mysql

I'm just learning `SQL` and have been using a couple of different tools (`sql fiddle` and `www sql designer`) to help.  I've been using `sql designer` then feeding that into `sql fiddle` to test my queries.  However, `sql designer` seems not to agree with `sql fiddle` on proper syntax.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `facts`;

CREATE TABLE `facts` (
   `factsID` INTEGER(10) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
   `sourceID` INTEGER(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `factTXT` MEDIUMTEXT(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `citiationID` INTEGER(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `factCreated` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`factsID`)
 )ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,`citiationID` INTEGER(10) NULL DEFAULT
>   NULL,`factC' at line 4

I don't know if this link will work with the error, but sqlFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b8d5/2/0.

Comment: Fiddle works for me.

Comment: Why don't you take a varchar for the length 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do not include a size for the `MEDIUMTEXT`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8548a)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `facts`;

CREATE TABLE `facts` (
   `factsID` INTEGER(10) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
   `sourceID` INTEGER(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `factTXT` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,  -- NO INCLUDED SIZE
   `citiationID` INTEGER(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `factCreated` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`factsID`)
 )ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: that was it!  Thanks.  I've got quite a bit of learning to do to figure out all the different text types and when to use them.

Comment: General tip: Just remove one line each time until the error disapear to find where the error is, then check the manual. For example in this case I didnt know `MEDIUMTEXT` exist I usually just use `TEXT`, but once I found where the error is, the solution was easy.